# How to 'easily' obtain the quadratic form of an inverse?

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

**How to 'easily' obtain the quadratic form of an inverse?**

---

**x = $v^TA^{-1}\,v$**

- $A$ is a symmetric invertible matrix of real numbers, it is also positive-definite and sparse.
- $v$ is a vector with few non-zero values.

---

-- It is too expensive to find the inverse.

-- To solve a single linear system is ok, but I need to find $x$ for many different vectors $v$, so solving $A\,y=v$ is not a viable solution.

-- Since there are few non-zero values in $v$: $A\,v$ , $v^Tv$ and $v^TA\,v$ can be obtained very easily.

---

In the specific situation where

$[\,v\,v^T]\,A = A\,[\,v\,v^T]$

we would have:

$x\,v^TA\,v = v^TA^{-1}\,v\,v^TA\,v = v^TA^{-1}A\,v\,v^Tv = v^Tv\,v^Tv \Rightarrow \boxed{x = \frac{(v^Tv)^2}{v^TA\,v}}$

This made me think that maybe there is some similar expression for a general case (without the commutative property).

---

Question: **Is there a better way to write $x$?**

Comment: Maybe it is easy to find $p$ such that $v=Ap$ using a reduction method exploiting the few nonzeros of $v$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)?

Comment: I have tried that, however, **p** will be a 'full vector' (it will have many nonzeros), I could not write it in a way that I would only need to invert a smaller block of **A**... =/

Comment: I believe my linear solver uses the Cholesky Decomposition, however, as I said, It is too expensive to solve **Ay=v**, because I need to find **x** for many different vectors **v**.

Did you have another suggestion for using the Cholesky Decomposition, or you mentioned it as a way to solve the linear system?

Comment: You can compute the Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^T$ once, then solve $L^T y = v$ for each of your many vectors (which is fast, because $L$ is sparse and triangular), then compute the inner product $y^T y$. I'm not sure what you mean by $p$ will be a full vector---what is $p$?

Comment: I just now realized that the comment about $p$ was in reference to N74's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to compute $x_i$ for each of $n$ different vectors $v_i$. If $A$ is $m \times m$, the naive apprach would take $O(n m^3)$ time. However, you can compute the Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^T$ in $O(m^3)$ time once, then solve the triangular system $L^T y_i = v_i$ in $O(m^2)$ time, then compute $x_i = y_i^T y_i$ in $O(m)$ time, for a total running time of $O(n m^2 + m^3)$; this is significant when $n$ is large.

If $A$ is sparse, good Cholesky solvers will give sparse factors, and this computation can be quite fast: on my laptop, using [cholmod through python](https://pythonhosted.org/scikits.sparse/cholmod.html) I can compute the cholesky decomposition of a random one million by one million matrix with ~two million nonzero entries in just under a second, and given the factorization can compute $x$ for a dense vector $v$ in about 20 ms. If $n$ is large enough, you probably won't beat this approach for speed.

There are other decompositions you could use (an LDL decomposition often has better numerical stability, and the SVD might make sense if your matrix is low rank), but in general you cannot compute $v^T A^{-1} v$ without computing some kind of decomposition.

Comment: Hmm, so you think the best we can do for an exact result is to compute the Cholesky decomposition?
Maybe we could think in something that approaches the result but with a lower computational cost?...

Comment: If you're open to approximate answers, there are lots of possibilities with different tradeoffs. What makes sense depends on many factors: how big is $A$? How sparse? How many vectors $v$ do you want to evaluate? How well-conditioned is $A$? How accurate of an answer do you want?

Comment: Also, note that the packages used to find a sparse Cholesky factor are different from those used to find a dense one---for instance, in Python, you would use scipy.sparse.cholmod instead of numpy.linalg.cholesky. This will do things like find a good permutation of the matrix to reduce fill-in of the resulting factors. Most linear algebra packages offer special tools to work with sparse matrices.

Comment: Some more information I could give about **A**: its size should be at least 5000x5000, up to something around 500000x500000. It is very sparse, each line should not have more than 18 non-zero elements.
If **A** is **m**x**m**, I would like to evaluate something around **m** vectors **v**. I have not much information about how well-conditioned **A** is, only that it is always invertible. Under 10% of error would be already acceptable for an approximate result.
If you have other ideas beside the Cholesky approach I would be glad to hear, thank you anyway! :)

Comment: I added some timing information to the answer---if you haven't already, you should try the Cholesky approach, using a library like cholmod or eigen to compute the decomposition. I doubt you will beat that approach for the sizes you describe if $n$ is large enough. If you can't compute a decomposition, your matrix is well-conditioned, and you can tolerate inaccuracy, you might consider computing $x$ with something like the [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to implement both approaches: Cholesky Decomposition and Conjugate Gradient.